# How can I reflect to attribute but not trigger a rerender in lit-element?

Tags: web-component, lit-element

I am converting a custom element dropdown over to lit-element. The way the existing element shows the dropdown options is by setting an `expanded` boolean attribute on the element, and the options are shown/hidden via css:

```css
my-element:not([expanded]) .options-container {
  display: none;
}

my-element[expanded] .options-container {
  display: block;
}
```

The component doesn't need to do any rerenders because the logic is all in the css.

How can I achieve this behavior with lit-element, and not rerender the component? Rerendering can be costly if there are a lot of dropdown options.

I have tried implementing a `shouldUpdate` that returns false if only `expanded` has changed - but this causes lit-element not to reflect `expanded` to the attribute when set via a property, which is necessary in order to show/hide via css.

This is what I have, which doesn't work:

```js
class MyDropdown extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      expanded: { type: Boolean, reflect: true },
      ...
    };
  }

  shouldUpdate(changedProperties) {
    if (changedProperties.has('expanded') && changedProperties.size === 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // disable shadow-dom
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Note that I am *not* using shadow dom yet, not sure if that would change the solution. I'm on lit-element 2.2.1.

Comment: The problem, of course, is that reflecting the attribute when the property is changed is part of rendering, so when you tell it not to render you're telling it not to change the attribute. A question: You say "Rerendering can be costly if there are a lot of dropdown options," which is arguably true, but have you encountered an actual performance problem? Have you profiled the actual cost of rendering vs. not rendering when there are a lot of options?

Comment: In IE, dropdowns with over 200 options can take 2 seconds to open/close. I figured out a workaround using lit-html's `guard` directive, but just not doing a rerender at all seems like the more ideal solution. I guess I can understand attributes updating being part of the render, but this should still be configurable.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You should post your `guard` solution as an answer for the benefit of future googlers.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker did you found any solution on above issue?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to not use **LitElement's** `static properties` or `@Property` decorator. Write your own property implementation like this:

```
class MyDropdown extends LitElement {

  _expanded = false;

  get expanded() {
    return this._expanded;
  }

  set expanded(val) {
    this._expanded = val;

    // Manually setting the property and reflecting attribute.
    if (val) {
      this.setAttribute('expanded', '');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('expanded');
    }
  }

  // disable shadow-dom
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Similarly, you can listen for `attributeChangedCallback` lifecycle event and adjust `_expanded` property whenever user changes the attribute and not property.

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to add `expanded` to the `observedAttributes` list? Does lit-element provide a way to hook into that? Maybe I *do* use `static properties`, but don't call `requestUpdate` from the setter?

Comment: Yes you would need add it!